# NFS Cannot allocate memory

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, nfs

The other night I was trying to restart NFS services but then I received the following error messages:

```
kernel: [81818.428785] nfsd: unable to allocate nfsd_file_hashtbl
rpc.nfsd[15567]: error starting threads: errno 12 (Cannot allocate memory)
systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

That is a weird error to get considering that the system had 12+GB of RAM left in buff/cache. As far as I understand buff/cache memory - that is memory that is used by the kernel to cache information but still available to applications to use if they need RAM.

I then ran the following command:

```
sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

And the memory shifted from buff/cache to free and NFS started without any issues.

Everything that I'm reading suggests that is basically one of the worst things to do.

My question is that is this a bug in NFS or something else? It appears that this is a quite heated topic and I'm not arguing whether it is ok or not - all I can report is when I ran that NFS started without any issues and I am curious to know why.

I'm running Debian 10, with proxmox 6.3-6, NFS version 1:1.3.4-2.5+deb10u1

Edit:

I have also noticed issues with proxmox (ie VNC console not working or can't connect to different nodes) - running that mentioned command on both of my nodes clears up all of those issues.

Comment: First, there are multiple NFS servers, one runs in kernel space and others run in user space. Judging by the version number, it seems you are using nfs-kernel-server which may explain why the buffer memory is not claimed. Second, you are mentioning Proxmox: does your NFS server really run on a 12+ GB VM? Or is it running on the host? In the latter case, how is your RAM allocated to the VMs? How much remains available to the host?

Comment: The NFS server is ran on the host. The 12+GB is buff/cache on the host - for a total of 16GB of total RAM.

Comment: Interesting fix. `Writing to /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches allows one to request the kernel immediately drop as much clean cached data as possible.` https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-clear-the-buffer-pagecache-disk-cache-under-linux/

Comment: @DonnLee from what I've gathered - this doesn't do any harm per say - it just may make the kernel do some extra work to recache data (which may or may not contain data that was cached). Many people seem to suggest this is very bad practice - but I have yet to find an explanation or other workaround for this. I have since put this in my crontab and proxmox is running smoother and have not gotten any memory errors since.

Comment: I don't have an answer but I wanted to note that I ran into this exact issue and the only resolution seemed to be rebooting the NFS server host.